# Eclipse/GTK+ 3 wasting space with padding

Tags: eclipse, gtk

I install STS which is based on Eclispe on Fedora 15. Gnome3 is nice but Eclipse uses a lot of padding. How can I fix it?

There are only solutions for GTK 2.0

Answer (score 2):

The old solutions for GTK2 are still very effective on Gnome 3.
I'm using the GTK configuration from [this post](http://farjumper.livejournal.com/3855.html) and have an eclipse alias defining the environment:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/opt/eclipse/gtkrc-custom /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

I've actually modified the GTK configuration to not override my fonts; I like my system fonts (liberation, as described at [in.relation.to](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/MakingEclipseLookGoodOnLinuxRevisited)).